# Reload on click of a button without onclick attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website on softr.io.
It's a no-code builder to create a frontend for airtable data.

I would like to refresh a page on the click of a specific button.
I unfortunately have little customization and this is what I have so far:

```
<script>
//get the <button> element
const reloadButton = document. getElementsByTagName('button').innerHTML=='Save'
;

//add the listener
reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reloadPage);

//callback for the 'click' event
function reloadPage(){
    window.location.reload();
} 
</script>
```

It's not working (not so surprised haha)
[image: Error]

Please keep in mind I'm no developper and just trying to tinker with what I know.

Thank you for the help,
Joachim

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('button').innerHTML=='Save'` is a boolean, not an html element, so it won't have `addEventListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [document.getElementsByTagName function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) return a list of node and not a single one.

To retrive your button, you sould add an `identifier` to the button and retrieve it with the [getElementById function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) instead.

For example :

```js
const reloadButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
```

---

Then in your code you are doing the following :

```js
const reloadButton = document. getElementsByTagName('button').innerHTML=='Save'
```

In js, the `==` operator return a boolean so you are assiging the `boolean` to `reloadButton` instead of the button itself.

If the purpose of your code is to add **Save** to the button, you can do it the following way :

```js
//callback for the 'click' event
function reloadPage(){
    console.log("hello world")
    window.location.reload();
} 

const reloadButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

reloadButton.innerHTML = 'Save'

//add the listener
reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reloadPage);
```

```html
<button id="myButton"></button>
```

---

## Edit

In your case, it seems that you want to identify the button with the `innerText` **save**

In your case you can totally use the `getElementsByTagName` function which return the following as read in the documentation :

> A live HTMLCollection of elements with a matching tag name, in the order they appear. If no elements are found, the HTMLCollection is empty.

Then you can loop through the collection and add your function if the innerText is **save**

### Example :

```js
//callback for the 'click' event
function reloadPage(){
    console.log("hello world")
    window.location.reload();
} 

const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')

for (let button of buttons){
  if(button.innerText.toLowerCase() === "save"){
    button.addEventListener('click', reloadPage)
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Wrong button</button>
<button>save</button>
<button>Another wrong button</button>
```

*Note : If multiple buttons contains the save innerText, then all of these buttons will run the function onclick*

Comment: Thank you very much, my issue is that softr doesn't let the user add an ID to the button, the ID seems randomly generated. So I need to identify the button containing the word "save" and reload the page on click.
I am in my car but will try to figure it out once am back.

Thanks a lot for your help !!!


But I don't know if I'll keep posting my trials as I get downvoted when the script is shit...

Comment: I've edited my post please tee me if it's better for you

Comment: That is top noth, thank you so much for this detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

the `getElementsByTagName` method returns an array of elements,
if there is only one button on that page, you can access it by `reloadButton[0]`
Alternatively, you may use an id selector,
`document.getElementById("button_id")`
this would be way more convenient to work with

Comment: Thank you! I will try again with this in mind.

I'm amazed at how people managed to downvote my question when I literally have no idea about coding and spent an hour to end up with this bit of script...

Answer (score 1):

since your button is assigned an **ID** at runtime, you can't use the `document.getElementById()`

use `document.querySelector()` instead.

create a `div` and assign it an **ID**, then place your `button` inside it, use bellow code then;

```html
<div id="demo">
  <button>Reload</button>
</div>

<script>
    var btn = document.querySelector('#demo button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('button clicked');
    window.location.reload();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't do that in softr (yeah very limited...) but thank you so much for taking the time, I'll go with the answer from Renaud above.